# How to conditionally hide author name on Single.php if category is "news", otherwise if category is something else display author name?

Tags: categories, author, conditional-content

I would like to be able to conditionally hide the author's name on the Single.php if the Category name is equal to "News" and otherwise if the category is something else hide it. How do I go about doing this? The code I have below does not seem to work:

```
            <!-- header.php -->
        <?php get_header(); ?>
        <!-- /header.php -->

        <!-- 960 16 Column Grid -->
        <section class="container_16">

        <!-- Top Pagination -->
        <?php include('includes/top-pagination.php'); ?>
        <!-- /Top Pagination -->

        <div class="clear"></div>

            <!-- Post -->
            <article class="grid_10 single-post-content margin-top-60">

                <!-- Post Loop -->
                <?php if (have_posts()) while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <!-- Clear -->
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <!-- /Clear -->

                    <!-- Post Title -->
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <!-- /Post Title -->

                    <!-- Featured News Meta -->
                    <?php if(is_category('news')) { ?>
                    <p class="featured-news-post-meta"><?php echo get_the_date('m.d.Y'); ?></p>
                    <?php  } else { ?>
                    <p class="featured-news-post-meta">By <span class="featured-news-author"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span> / <?php echo get_the_date('m.d.Y'); ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <!-- /Featured News Meta -->

                    <!-- Post Content -->
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <!-- /Post Content -->

                    <?php //endif; ?>

                    <!-- Divider -->
                    <div class="separator"></div>
                    <!-- /Divider -->

                    <!-- Featured News Social Links -->
                    <?php include('includes/social.php'); ?>
                    <!-- /Featured News Social Links -->

                    <!-- Comments -->
                    <?php //comments_template( '', true ); ?>
                    <!-- /Comments -->

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <!-- /Post Loop -->

            </article>
            <!-- /Post -->

            <!-- What's Happening -->
            <div class="margin-top-60">
                <?php include('includes/whats-happening.inc.php'); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- /What's Happening -->

        </section>
        <!-- /960 16 Column Grid -->

        <!-- sidebar.php -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        <!-- /sidebar.php -->

        <!-- footer.php -->
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
        <!-- /footer.php -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_category` returns true if the current page being viewed is a category term page (i.e. a list of posts belonging to some term) and false otherwise. So inside `single.php` it will always return false.

If you want to check if a the current post in the Loop belongs to some category term, then you need to use [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term).

For example:

```
 <?php if( has_term('news','category') ) { ?>
      <p class="featured-news-post-meta"><?php echo get_the_date('m.d.Y'); ?></p>
 <?php  } else { ?>
      <p class="featured-news-post-meta">By <span class="featured-news-author"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span> / <?php echo get_the_date('m.d.Y'); ?></p>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `is_category()` where I believe you want [**`in_category()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/in_category)

`is_category()` is true on a category archive page, `in_category()` returns true if a post belongs to a particular or array of categories.

**EDIT** `in_category()` is just a wrapper for the generic `has_term()`, see Stephen's answer.